# String formating in Python when querying SQLite3

Tags: python, string, sqlite

I am creating an API app with SQlite3 in Python. It all works fine until I process an item with ' in the name column. The entry will get written to the DB but the code will break when I try getting that item from the database with this:

```py
received_data = {"name": "Example with ' name", "price": 43,...}
```

```sql
new_item = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name='{}'".format(received_data['name'])).fetchall()
```

I get this error:

```py
new_item = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name='{}'".format(received_data['name'])).fetchall()
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "name": syntax error
```

What is the best solution to this since I can't guess (I guess...) all the characters that someone might use in the name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `format` for this at all, it is dangerous. Use a parameterized query:

```
new_item = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name=?", (received_data['name'],)).fetchall()
```